# Control Instance of Watir-Webdriver from another file

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

How would I control an instance of Watir-Webdriver from another file? For example,
in a file webdriver.rb I have

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
class Crawler
    attr_accessor :browser
    def initialize
      self.browser = Watir::Browser.new
    end

    def goto_mypage
      browser.goto("http://www.mypage.com")
    end

    def kill
      browser.close
    end
  end

a = Crawler.new
```

Now how would I access a from the file "another_file.rb" with content like

```
a.goto("htttp://www.another_page.com")
a.goto_mypage
```

I've tried making requiring './webdriver.rb' in another_file.rb. And making the class Crawler part of a module and including that. Getting access to the methods across files is not a problem -- getting access to the webdriver instance is.

I've tried setting an instance variable @a = a in webdriver.rb and then accessing @a from another_file.rb.

I thought this would be simple, but it has me flummoxed.

Answer (score 0):

You may get more help if you include actual results. Are you getting a nil class error?

Is there a reason you cannot have `a = Crawler.new` in another_file.rb and then just refer to it in there?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm getting a nil class error
    `NoMethodError - undefined method 'goto' for nil:NilClass:` 
when trying to control a from another_file.rb
The error refers, let's say, to the method goto_mypage in webdriver.rb. I can't put  `a = Crawler.new` in the second file because the majority of the work that a is doing is defined in the webdriver.rb file. It has to sit and observe changes in a webpage. Very occasionally -- depending on whether the code in another_file.rb is called on -- I need a to check out a different page and the return to the original page it is monitoring.